# How to run bash functions in parallel and merge all output to one string in order?

Tags: string, bash, parallel-processing

I'm writing several bash-prompts functions in the style of [oh-my-git](https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git) and I want them to run in parallel and merge their output in order. Speed is of the essence and I want to avoid writing to any file system, be their in memory or on hard-drive.

My idea was to try to set variables in parallel but it's not doable in the same scope. GNU Parallel and parset does not seam to take in bash functions.

End of my .bashrc :

```sh
: "${ORIGINAL_PS1:=$PS1}"

PROMPT() {

    git="$(GIT_PROMPT)"
    pamac="$(PAMAC_PROMPT)"
    busich="$(BUSICH_PROMPT)"

    PS1="$git$pamac$busich$ORIGINAL_PS1"

}

PROMPT_COMMAND="PROMPT; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

(GIT_PROMPT, PAMAC_PROMPT and BUSICH_PROMPT being sourced bash functions)

Comment: Aside: all-caps user-defined function and variable names are bad form. All caps is reserved for names meaningful to the shell and operating system. Thus, `PROMPT_COMMAND` is all-caps because it's meaningful to the shell; `pamac_prompt` should be lowercase (or mixed-case), because it's user-defined. See the naming convention discussion in the POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html (a document purportedly specific to environment variables; however, shell variables share the same namespace).

Comment: If GIT_PROMPT runs something like `git status`, then git will already do a _lot_ of filesystem operations. The other ones probably access the filesystem as well. I'd say @Charles Duffy's answer is your best bet, but my actual advice would be to not overload the prompt with status of externals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To narrowly answer the question, spawning three process substitutions and concatenating their results will let the work happen in parallel, while generating output in a known order:

```
PS1=$(cat <(GIT_PROMPT) <(PAMAC_PROMPT) <(BUSICH_PROMPT))
```

Similarly, in bash 4.1 or later, you can explicitly start an external process and attach an automatically-assigned file descriptor to be used for reading its output:

```
# start GIT_PROMPT function in the background
exec {git_prompt_fd}< <(GIT_PROMPT)

# ...do other stuff...

# now, later, read its output
git_prompt=$(</dev/fd/$git_prompt_fd)
```

...keeping in mind that you want to avoid any operations that would block on writing to stdout until after the hard work inside your function is done.

---

However, I don't actually recommend that at all, *especially* in code as performance-sensitive as a prompt. Much better would be to review your functions and stop them from having *any* fork operations, any use of external commands, etc.; rather than adding *yet more* forks in the name of parallelization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't see this as _the_ optimizing step but one of many. Still I think it will shave off a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Use `env_parallel`

```
env_parallel --session
GIT_PROMPT() { echo stdoutgit; echo stderrgit >&2; sleep 2; }
PAMAC_PROMPT() { echo stdoutpamac; echo stderrpamac >&2; sleep 2; }
BUSICH_PROMPT() { echo stdoutbusich; echo stderrbusic >&2; sleep 2; }
PS1=`env_parallel -k ::: GIT_PROMPT PAMAC_PROMPT BUSICH_PROMPT`
env_parallel --endsession
```

Solution 2: export functions

```
GIT_PROMPT() { echo stdoutgit; echo stderrgit >&2; sleep 2; }
export -f GIT_PROMPT
PAMAC_PROMPT() { echo stdoutpamac; echo stderrpamac >&2; sleep 2; }
export -f PAMAC_PROMPT
BUSICH_PROMPT() { echo stdoutbusich; echo stderrbusic >&2; sleep 2; }
export -f BUSICH_PROMPT
PS1=`parallel -k ::: GIT_PROMPT PAMAC_PROMPT BUSICH_PROMPT`
```

Only stdout is captured, so you will need to deal with stderr yourself (possibly just redirecting it to stdout).

(GNU Parallel uses tempfiles in `/tmp`, but tries very hard to clean these up - typically less than 1 ms after the file is created. The file is kept open, so activity to the file typically happens *after* it is removed).

Comment: Thanks, stack overflow ate my answer before I was done and I couldn't edit it after. I couldn't implement solution 2 properly since each functions calls more hidden bash functions that I didn't talk about. Well I exported them too, but now nothing shows up.